# WordPress Responsive Design: Sidebar with rounded corners

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, rounded-corners, sidebar

I'd like to create a WordPress theme inspired by the [behance.net](http://www.behance.net/) page.
Two questions:

1. How do I setup the grey sidebar and white content area properly.
2. On small screens (RWD) I'd like the sidebar to move underneath the content area, add padding on the sides and turn off border-radius. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by how do you set up the sidebar? do you have a starter code? can you post your code please

Answer (score 0):

Some basic suggestions...

Content and sidebar both need to be floated left so they stack on smaller screens

Use media queries in your css to add padding and remove rounded corners when viewed on smaller screens